# How to create a Button like this in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]
How to create a button with a list selecter like the pic shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `QToolButton` by setting up a `QMenu`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            icon=QtGui.QIcon("plus.png"),
            popupMode=QtWidgets.QToolButton.InstantPopup
        )
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(button)
        menu.addAction(QtGui.QIcon("insert.png"), "Insert multiple rows")
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction("Place new rows above selected row")
        menu.addAction("Place new rows bellow selected row")
        menu.addAction("Place new rows at the end of the data view")
        button.setMenu(menu)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar("tools")
        toolbar.addWidget(button)
        tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
        self.setCentralWidget(tableWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `QtGui.QComboBox`
Hope it's what you need